# pygame.image.load(os.path.join) not working

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me why this won't work(it works on my other computer).

```
BLUE_BULLETS = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("c:\\pixel_laser_blue"))
```

[location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82CeH.png)

I don't think I messed up the location, did I?

Thanks in advance!

Help me with python pygame.

Comment: Why do you use `join` instead of just loading it directly? Also, what *won't work*?

Comment: You can look at how to enable viewing file extensions on windows [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/common-file-name-extensions-in-windows-da4a4430-8e76-89c5-59f7-1cdbbc75cb01)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the file extension. Windows displays files without their ending so that it is easier to read, but in reality, almost every file has a file extension. This is `.py` for python files, `.txt` for text files, and `.png` for PNG image files. In your case simply `pygame.image.load("C:\\pixel_laser_blue.png")` should work.